# Non-Dell Battery Not Detected on Dell Inspiron 1545

Tags: dell, battery, inspiron

I bought a new battery and power cord from Amazon which is not Dell OEM. Ubuntu is not recognizing the batter at all. It say's "Not Present".

Is it reasonable to assume that this is a hardware issue with the battery since it's not OEM or is there a software issue/patch/update for this?

Comment: Go into the BIOS of the system (usually F2 or F6 or F12, it should say on the initial power on screen as "Setup").  Check if the system in the BIOS detects the battery.  If it does not then the battery isn't going to work with your computer.

Comment: The Bios showed the battery as "healthy" but 0% charged. Looks like I need to buy a Dell OEM battery.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that this is a hardware issue with either the battery not reporting it's status at all or with the laptop not being able / refusing to communicate with a non-OEM part.

Comment: Makes sense. Ubuntu is awesome! Watch out MS, here come :-)